# Reshape from flattened indices in Python

Tags: python, space-filling-curve

I have an image of size M*N whose pixels coordinates has been flattened to a 1D array according to a space-filling curve (i.e. not a classical rasterization where I could have used reshape).

I thus process my 1D array (flattened image) and I then would like to reshape it to a M*N array (initial size).

So far, I have done this with a for-loop:

```
for i in range(img_flat.size):
    img_res[x[i], y[i]] = img_flat[i]
```

x and y being the x and y pixels coordinates according to my path scan.

However, I am wondering how to do this in a unique line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are numpy arrays of dimension 1 and lengths `n`, and `img_flat` also has length `n` `img_res` is a numpy array of dimension 2 `(h, w)` such that `h*w = n, then:

```
img_res[x, y] = img_flat
```

Should suffice

Comment: Yes, it is even simpler than my second solution! I always forget this tip!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was easy:

```
vec = np.arange(0, seg.size, dtype=np.uint)
img_res[x[vec], y[vec]] = seg[vec]
```